# databricks-dbx HTTPError 403 Client Error

Tags: databricks-dbx

I am running some jobs using:

- dbx version 0.7.4
- pyspark 3.2.2
- delta-spark 2.0.0
- Python 3.8.1

I am following the guidelines from : https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/assets/?h=dbx+launch+assets

I run the following commands

```bash
dbx deploy <my-workflow> --assets-only
dbx launch <my-workflow> --from-assets
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: submit_run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'permissions'
```

On the `deployment.yml` I have included this:

```yaml
custom:
  basic-cluster-props: &basic-cluster-props
    spark_version: "10.4.x-scala2.12"
    node_type_id: "Standard_D3_v2"

  basic-settings: &basic-settings
    libraries:
      - pypi:
          package: "pyyaml"
    permissions:
      access_control_list:
        - user_name: "userid" 
          permission_level: "IS_OWNER"
        - group_name: "admins"
          permission_level: "CAN_MANAGE"
        - group_name: "rolename"
          permission_level: "CAN_MANAGE"

  basic-static-cluster: &basic-static-cluster
    new_cluster:
      <<: *basic-cluster-props
      num_workers: 1
    <<: *basic-settings

environments:
  default:
    strict_path_adjustment_policy: true
    workflows:
      - name: "current-integration-test"
        <<:
          - *main-static-cluster
        spark_python_task:
          python_file: "file://tests/integration/cp/silver/test_myjob_job.py"
          parameters: ["--conf-file", "file:fuse://conf/int/cp.yml","--cov=dlite"]
```

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was a bug in `dbx` which was fixed with the latest 0.7.6 release. Please upgrade to the new version and try again.

Root cause is that `permissions` section is not acceptable by the RunSubmit API which is used under the hood of assets-based launch. We made it failsafe to improve the customer experience, but please take a note that the `permissions` setting will not be applied.